# Is there a way to retrieve Activity Logs from Azure ACS?

Tags: azure

I would like to build some functionality that will allow me to analyse how users of my public web sites use various identity providers to log-in.

I have multiple web sites connected to ACS through WIF. ACS provides identity federation with Social Network logins and also with my custom STS.

I would like to be able to retrieve the "Activity Log" from ACS. Something along the following lines:

```
1. RP: Web1; IdP: Google; Claims: [email: user1@gmail.com, name: User One]; Time: 15:37
2. RP: Web2; IdP: Custom; Claims: [email: user2@custom.com, name: User Two]; Time: 15:38
3. RP: Web1; IdP: Facebook; Claims: [email: user3@email.com, name: User Three]; Time: 15:39
```

(this is just a simplification, I understand each provider sends different claims, etc).

I was hoping I could retrieve something like that using management service, but I can't find a way.

Other option I explored is to add RP-STS to the claims chain: Web -> RP-STS -> ACS -> IdP. But it feels like bit of an overkill to add another hop to the chain just to collect the usage information. Is there any smarter way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. I am afraid you cannot retrieve such information today. You have to do the audit logging yourself. Which, if you need that simplified version of the information would not be very hard to achieve without the intermediate STS.

I would do the following:

- Pick up some [event from the WsFederationAuthenticationModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee727479.aspx) ([SessionSecurityTokenCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.wsfederationauthenticationmodule.sessionsecuritytokencreated.aspx) might be a good choice)
- In that event handler gather everything I need, including current running application identification, and write it asynchronously to Azure Table Storage
- pack the above code in separate class library and reference it from all Web Apps I have

My idea is to write to an Azure Storage Table, because I think it just fits perfectly for the scenario. I can have practically unlimited number of web apps writing to Azure Table Service. And if I choose the Partition Key/Row Key combinations carefully I will have infinite audit log store. The main question for designing the Azure Table is really about how you are going to read the data.